# Знання мови в ідеалі

Tags: вживання-слів

В резюме фахівця з філологічною освітою є таке речення: "В ідеалі володію російською, українською, англійською мовами". Подібне вживання слова "ідеал" чую не вперше.
Однак за [тлумачним «Словником української мови» в 11 т.](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html) іменник ідеал має такі значення:

> ІДЕА́Л, у, чол.
>
> 1. Найвища мета, до якої прагнуть люди і яка керує їхньою діяльністю тощо.
> 2. кого, чого. Взірець досконалості.  //  чий. Про того, хто є для когось втіленням найкращих якостей тощо.

[Онлайн-версія тлумачного «Словника української мови» в 20 т.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=38719&page=1207) до вказаних значень надано сталий вислів

> ◇ (1) **В ідеа́лі** – у найкращому варіанті. Офіційні дистриб'ютори радять
>   перед придбанням факсу пересвідчитися в наявності в продавця
>   сертифіката на товар або – в ідеалі – заздалегідь переглянути бюлетень
>   Мінзв'язку (із журн.); – В ідеалі сирки й делікатесне масло повинні
>   мати смак і структуру домашнього сиру, – розповідає директор фабрики
>   (з газ.).

Чи мотивованим є вживання виразу *в ідеалі* в наведеному вище контексті?

Comment: На жаль, я поки погано уявляю, де шукати відповідь, але для мене це запитання - про різницю речень "володіти чимось *в ідеалі*" та "володіти чимось *ідеально*". Перший варіант звучить ніби про бажану характеристику, а другий - про рівень володіння вже наявного. Хоча ці мої міркування трохи перегукуються із наведеними вами прикладами, це все ж суб'єктивна думка.

Answer (score 4):

В Інтернеті є дуже мало статей, де вживається словосполучення "знати в ідеалі" (ось приклад [1](http://murkots.ru/rizne/dresiruvannja-sobak-2/624-opis-porodi-sobak-mops-i-dogljad-za-porodoju.html) та [2](http://royal-mac.com/ua/blog.html)):

> Знати в ідеалі техніку ефективного переконання

Крім того, жодний із переглянутих мною словників ([1](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%20%D0%B2%20%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), [2](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), а також СУМ) не дали підстав для того, щоб підтвердити те, що ми можемо сказати "знати мову в ідеалі".

Я гадаю, що краще сказати "Я ідеально/досконало володію англійською мовою" для того, щоб точно уникнути помилки.

Answer (score 2):

Проаналізував [193 трапляння словосполучення «в ідеалі» в корпусі ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%B2+%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96), серед них:

- 166 разів вживається в значенні «в ідеальному випадку, в найкращому разі», як, власне, й зафіксовано в СУМ-20:

  > Кількість їжі має бути невеликою: в ідеалі [в ідеальному випадку] — скільки поміститься в двох долонях, складених разом.
- 16 разів уживається без якогось фразеологічного значення, просто як сполучення «в» й «ідеал» на кшталт:

  > Зневірившися в ідеалі, якого шукав [зневірившись у своєму ідеалі], Іуда продав свого вчителя не тільки з мотивів матеріальних, але й щоб повернути собі втрачену людську гідність.
- 1 раз уживається в значенні «в ідеальному вигляді, в ідеальній формі»:

  > Ми лише прагнемо до абсолютної свободи слова, хоч в ідеалі її не існує [хоч свободи слова в ідеальному вигляді не існує].

  і ще 3 рази, які можна класифікувати і як «в ідеальному випадку», і як «в ідеальному вигляді».
- 1 раз уживається в значенні «ідеально»:

  > Тут все підігнано майже в ідеалі [ідеально], щоб кожен, хто або живе, або гостює тут, почував себе якомога комфортніше і міг поринути у вир звичних саме для нього епох, часів та подій. <sub>//Валентина Коляда, фантастична повість-казка «Пригоди Романа та його друзів на Дріоді» (Кам'янець-Подільський, «Медобори-2006», 2014)</sub>
- 4 рази я не зрозумів і 2 рази не зміг класифікувати.

Висновок: Зазвичай «в ідеалі» вживається або в значенні «в ідеальному випадку, в найкращому разі», як зазначено в СУМ-20, або в прямому значенні — в інших значеннях (зокрема замість слова «ідеально») вживається вкрай рідко. При цьому слід зазначити, що корпус ГРАК-3 складається не лише з бездоганно написаних текстів, окремі випадки можуть виявитися й помилками авторів. Тому я не раджу використовувати «в ідеалі» замість «ідеально», мені особисто це трішки ріже слух (можливо, такий ужиток припустимий у високому стилі, до якого я не звик, але в типових ситуаціях він не сприймається).

<sub>Повний перелік класифікованих варіантів можна подивитись [тут](/revisions/4912/2).</sub>